# Pure JavaScript image manipulation

Tags: javascript, node.js, png, image-manipulation

I have a use case where I want to created (a) a Node application that (b) performs basic image manipulations (PNG resize and crop) but (c) where I cannot have external dependencies like native libraries, GraphicsMagick, ImageMagick, PhantonJS, Inkscape, etc.

It all has to be done in pure JavaScript.

Given how simple the manipulation I want to do is (just PNG resize and crop) this doesn't seem impossible. However, I cannot find a crop/resize library that doesn't ultimately have an external or native dependency.

Does such a genuinely pure JavaScript library exist for crop/resize? How difficult would it be to implement this in pure JavaScript, if I had to do it myself? And where should I start?

Alternatively, is there a suitable C function for this that I could compile using emscripten, for example?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=JavaScript%20library%20crop%2Fresize

Comment: @JamesG. all great stuff if I could use a headless browser, such as Phantom JS, a DOM implementation, such as js-dom. However, they all have external (native) dependencies.

Comment: Handling PNGs in pure Javascript is *possible* -- for a generously broad interpretation of "possible". Javascript can manipulate binary files with eaze; decompressing and then *re*-compressing the raw image data is not that easy (this requires a pure JS version of Flate and Deflate), but still within the realm of "doable". However, I don't believe it will be fast.

Comment: @Jongware, thanks. Fast isn't a requirement. The only constraint is that I cannot reply on a native dependency of any sort.

Comment: Server side resizing and croping is a pretty simple work, using languages such as C# or PHP. Have you considered using Javascript just for visual and then send the selected measures to server side code to perform?

Comment: @LcSalazar, thanks. The application is a command-line utility. It will be run manually once-in-a-while. Hence, I don't care so much about speed. The image manipulation part is one small piece - and a "nice to have" at that. So I wouldn't walk away from Node if it was not possible. However, I want to avoid binaries and external dependency of any kind. Uploading the images to a server to do the cropping and resizing would be an external dependency.

Comment: For JPG files, [jpg-js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jpeg-js) works just fine. For PNG, give [node-png](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-png) a try. For future reference, npmjs.org is your friend and you should try libraries it finds when you search for them =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermansm npmjs.org is a close friend of mine. I saw node-png and it does half the job (which gets me half way to where I want to be). What it gives me is the raw bitmap data. The next task is to crop and resize it. Cropping is easy. Scaling isn't. Any ideas on that? BTW up voted your comment for recognizing/suggesting a good starting point. Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

OK, I ended up rolling my own, which I have released as a NPM package here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/jimp

Example usage is:

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

var lenna = new Jimp("lenna.png", function () {
    this.crop(100, 100, 300, 200) // crop
        .resize(220, 220) // resize
        .write("lenna-small-cropped.png"); // save
});
```

The breakthrough was finding a JavaScript bicubic two-pass scaling algorithm here: https://github.com/grantgalitz/JS-Image-Resizer

Kudos to Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans for pointing the right direction to take and to Grant Galitz for an amazing scaling algorithm.

Comment: Thank u and I'm surprised there's little feedback on it. I had to modify it a bit to work directly with buffers and it definitely looks great for small operations. Great job!

Comment: @IgorR, thanks. If you have any improvements, please open an issue or make a pull request: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp

Comment: what I did is incomplete and works only with jpg, it's a dirty implementation not good enough for a pull, just made it work for my purposes. When I have some time will try to complete it for png and improve the code, and then make a pull request.
I'm just wondering how most people can be happy with the burden of *Magicks when it's totally possible to go without.

Comment: Jimp - the "JavaScript Image Manipulation Program" - is awesome. I just came across it this evening. It resized 8K ~ 200x300 images in 190 seconds. I plan to explore its many other tricks in the next few days. In the mean time: Bravo!

Comment: I've been using Jimp for a few months now. I use it as a fallback from sharp (because sharp is heaps faster, but often doesn't install). That said, kudos @OliverMoran, great work! It's everything it says on the box: dependency free and works well.

Comment: @OliverMoran I want to change a coloured images to purely black and white (not grey scale). I am trying your gem but wasn't able to find the correct option. I am trying with RGB values. Please if you can guide me in right direction.


Jimp.read(input_file, function (err, lenna) {
    if (err) throw err;
    lenna.color([
     { apply: 'red', params: [ -256 ] },
     { apply: 'green', params: [ -256 ] },
     { apply: 'blue', params: [ -256 ] },
 ]);     
     lenna.write(output_file);
});

Comment: @OliverMoran Precisely, I am trying to change the bitdepth from 8 to 1 of my image.

Comment: Does JIMP work in browser or client javascript too?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to compare Node.js modules for images manipulation - https://github.com/ivanoff/images-manipulation-performance

```
author's results:
  sharp.js : 9.501 img/sec; done in 10.525585 sec;
  canvas.js : 8.246 img/sec; done in 12.12766 sec;
  gm.js : 4.433 img/sec; done in 22.557112 sec;
  gm-imagemagic.js : 3.654 img/sec;
  lwip.js : 1.203 img/sec;
  jimp.js : 0.445 img/sec;
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, but I found the link above quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Example of resize and crop using pure javascript image manipulation with [MarvinJ](https://www.marvinj.org):

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var canvas3 = document.getElementById("canvas3");

image = new MarvinImage();
image.load("https://i.imgur.com/gaW8OeL.jpg", imageLoaded);

function imageLoaded(){
  imageOut = image.clone()
  image.draw(canvas1) 
  // Crop
  Marvin.crop(image, imageOut, 50, 50, 100, 100);
  imageOut.draw(canvas2);
  // Scale
  Marvin.scale(image, imageOut, 100);
 imageOut.draw(canvas3); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.7.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200"></canvas><br/>
<canvas id="canvas3" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: you could do this with node-canvas and then save to a file.  I am trying to use MarvinJ in Node which I am having difficulty with